# Bash - connect to ssh (unauthorized), grab MOTD to file and exit

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to grab MOTDs of many network devices without authenticating. On ssh connect, device will print out MOTD and ask for a password. I don't want to login, just grab MOTD to a file and quit.

I tried playing with `ssh -o BatchMode=yes`, but that will not return anything except permission denied.

Basically I need a MOTD grabber.

**EDIT:** I do not need a banner (service version) but MOTD. Some devices will print MOTD before logging in. I need to grab that output and kill ssh connection.

Comment: As far as I know, motd is only printed after login, so no luck there.  It you connect to the SSH port (22) using telnet, you will get the SSH version back, but not motd.

Comment: That's  sounds like penetration testing....

Comment: @Nic3500: Take a look at `banner` option of sshd (openssh).

Comment: @Nic3500 Some Cisco devices will print MOTD before logging in. Banner is not a MOTD, banner is a service version.

Comment: ah ok, I admit I was basing my comment on experience on unix systems only, not network devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
ssh -T -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no server 2>&1 | sed '$d' >file
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and why you think it would answer the question? From what I understand, the important part is `2>&1` because the SSH service displays the MotD on the standard error, NOT the standard output. Am I right?

Comment: @breversa: This redirects ssh's stderr (2) to stdout (1) and then to `sed` to remove last line before writing data to a file.